# Find an object in DOM without using standard DOM element selection method

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning javascript. And I stumbled upon this example code which makes me very confused.

```html
<html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>xxxxx</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function a() {
            let x = parseInt(Form1.val1.value);
            let y = parseInt(Form1.val2.value);
            alert("Sum \n" + (x + y));
        }
    </script>
    </head>
  <body text="red">
    <h1> xxxxx </h1>
    
    <form name="Form1">
        <input type="text" name="val1"><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="val2">
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" value="Calul" onclick="a()">

    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Regardless of its content, this is a working code. What I cannot understand is that why using directly Form1 (The "name" of the form) can work here. (However, when I do the same to other element such as `<p>`, it doesn't work)

I always thought we need to get everything (With pure JS) by using document.getElementByID / ByClass etc. in order to find the element in the HTML to manipulate.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a long story, mostly about legacy features of DOM, somewhat covered in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables). In a nutshell, while it's still possible to use this approach, it's better to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The `onclick` attribute on an element is a way to bind the click event directly. It will execute whatever is inside the quotes as Javascript (in this case, calling the `a()` function) when the element is clicked.

It's considered better practice to bind events using the `addEventListener` method from within Javascript (unless you're using frameworks like React or Angular which have their own ways of doing event binding).

You can read more about DOM onevent handlers here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers

Answer (score 0):

Input elements are a special element that has a onclick attribute. It is better to use the addEventListener method to add an click listener to whatever element you want to make clickable.

eg.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript addEventListener()</h2>

<p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a click event to a paragraph.</p>

<p id="clickableP">CLICKABLE PARAGRAPH ELEMENT</p>



<script>
document.getElementById("clickableP").addEventListener("click", buttonClicked);

function buttonClicked() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph was clicked"
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

More info:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp